# Depth of field effect – BokehPass doesnt work correctly on iOS (iPhone 7)

Tags: ios, three.js, shader, post-processing

I have implemented depth of field effect using BokehPass (based on https://threejs.org/examples/?q=dof#webgl_postprocessing_dof)

It works great on desktops (PC or Mac) but on my iPhone its broken. It only blur whole scene (based on the settings – so it is actually doing something), but its missing the focus (sharp) area. So if “focus” value is set to 0, whole screen is sharp, when I raise it, whole screen is going blurry. On desktop it works as expected – raising focus value “move” focus area, so foreground is blurry, background is blurry, but the focus area is sharp.

Nothing fancy in my code:

```
this._composer = new EffectComposer(this._renderer);

    const renderPass = new RenderPass(this._scene, camera);

    this._bokehPass = new BokehPass(this._scene, camera, {
      focus: 1.0,
      aperture: 0.025,
      maxblur: 0.01,

      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight,
    });
    const gammaCorrectionPass = new ShaderPass(GammaCorrectionShader);

    this._composer.addPass(renderPass);
    this._composer.addPass(gammaCorrectionPass);
    this._composer.addPass(this._bokehPass);
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you mind demonstrating the issue with a live example? BTW: Gamma correction pass should be after DOF.

Comment: I have created simple demo here: https://www.kroscloud.com/Tester (wait a few secs to load the 3D model)  Focus point is in the middle of the tank. On the PC/Mac it works, but on the iPhone x iPad everything is blurry, without the focus point

Comment: Do you see any difference if you remove the call of `setPixelRatio()`?

Comment: No, there is no diff when I remove setPixelRatio()  
When the GLTF model is loaded and I add it to the scene I need to call bokehPass.uniforms['aperture'].value to kinda "activate" it. But changing any other 
setting - focus or maxBlur, doesnt do this. Looks like there is some "trigger" activated when setting the aperture. If I remove this setter after model is added to the scene, everything is blurry, without the focus area.
 Cant this be a clue? 
Maybe iOS needs to trigger something else... 
Btw. I tested it on Android devices and it works correctly there.

Comment: Ok, the thing with aperture uniform was just my bug, so... it is not a clue... I tested one more time the DOF example at ThreeJS on my iPad, and it works ok. So what is different in my case...

Comment: @Mugen87 Please, no idea? It is important for us. Thanks a lot

Comment: Does it work if you disable `logarithmicDepthBuffer`? It seems you are setting it to `true` which should not be necessary for this scene.

Comment: Oh man, thats it. logarithmicDepthBuffer was the problem. Thanks a lot for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a @Mugen87 hint, the problem on iOS was caused by renderer.logarithmicDepthBuffer set to true. If set to false, focus area on iOS devices works as expected.